libusb_get_next_timeout always returns 0
I am trying to implement asynchronous event handling using libusb library.
Currently I am trying to call handle event through API
libusb_handle_events(context, &tv)

So before calling libusb_handle_events(), I am checking for the timeout for the next event using
struct timeval tv;
libusb_get_next_timeout(devinfo->usb_context, &tv) //this call is returing 0 always.

return value 1 represents success, 0 represents no pending events.
